# Exercise Self Study Help

Tags: c++

I've started learning C++ and am working through some exercises in the C++ Primer Plus book.

In chapter 5 one of the exercises is:

> Write a program that uses an array of
>   char and a loop to read one word at a
>   time until the word done is entered.
>   The program should then report the
>   number of words entered (not counting
>   done). A sample run could look like this:
>
> ```
> Enter words (to stop, type the word done):
> anteater birthday category dumpster
> envy finagle geometry done for sure
> You entered a total of 7 words.
> ```
>
> You should include the cstring header
>   file and use the strcmp() function to
>   make the comparison test.

Having a hard time figuring this out. It would be much easier if I could use if statements and logical operators but I'm restricted to using only:

1. Loops
2. Relational Expressions
3. char arrays

Branching statments (ie if, case/switch ) and logical operators are not allowed.

Can anyone give me hints to push me in the right direction?

Edit: Clarification. The input must be one string. So, several words for one input.

Comment: It's one thing if a book forbids you to use ugly crutches, but this is forbidding you to use the tools you *should* use to solve the problem. Why not skip this exercise.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: ...or ignore the pointless restrictions, and instead write the most sensible code you can to produce the correct end result.

Comment: lol, I was thinking the same thing. After a few minutes I questioned whether this was a good exercise problem.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers: There is a C++ Primer answer book also available!!!

Comment: There might be for C++ Primer but not sure about C++ Primer Plus.

Comment: char arrays ? `strcmp` ? isn't this a C Primer book ? I would strongly suggest you dump this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: oops, spec says to read into an array of char… I'm not going to bother editing, this is really stupid. `std::string` contains an array of char too!

```
cin.exceptions( ios::badbit ); // avoid using if or && to check error state

int n;
string word;
for ( n = 0; cin >> word, strcmp( word.c_str(), "done" ) != 0; ++ n ) ;
```

I prefer

```
string word;
int n;
for ( n = 0; cin && ( cin >> word, word != "done" ); ++n ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this pseudo-code:

```
while (input != done) 
  do things
end-while
```

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A loop could also act as a conditional...

Answer (score 0):

```
integer count
char array input

count = 0
read input
while(input notequal "done")
 count++
 read input
done
print count
```

- The `input notequal "done"` part can
  be done as `strcmp(input,"done")`. If
  the return value is `0` is means
  input is same as `"done"`
- reading input can be done using `cin`

Answer (score 0):

You should define a max len for char arrays first. Then a do while loop would be sufficient. You chould check the string equality with the strcmp function. That should be ok.